# Docker persistent data linking

Tags: docker, dockerfile

#### I am trying to create 3 container Docker environment:

- A data-only container
- A database container
- An app container

#### I create the `data-only` and the `database` containers by running:

`docker run -d -t --name dbdata -v /dbdata data-only`

`docker run -d -t --volumes-from dbdata --name db hdf5`

I have tested for persistence between the `data-only` container and the `database` container and it works.

#### Linking the `app` container:

Here is where I am running into issues. When I link the `app` container to the `database` container running:

`docker run -i -t -p 5000:5001 --link db:db --name app py-opencv`

**I cannot find my `data-only` volume `/dbdata`. I have read everything I can to figure out why, but to no avail.**

When I run `docker inspect app` I can see the link:

```
"Links": [
            "/db:/app/db"
        ]
```

And I also see: `"Mounts": []` and `"VolumesFrom": null` not sure if that is an issue.

When I run `docker exec app cat /etc/hosts` I see:

```
172.17.0.4  1cab4ab3c886
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  db 5e291000ab13
```

**Please help**

---

### Dockerfiles (with some of the guts stripped out for brevity):

#### `data-only`

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV HOME /root

CMD ["true"]
```

#### `database`

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV HOME /root

# Install dependencies via apt-get
# Build HDF5
# Cleanup

EXPOSE 5001
```

#### `app`

```
FROM python:3.5

ENV HOME /root

# Install dependencies
# Install Python packages
# Build OpenCV and dependencies

# Update environment and directories
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV HDF5_DIR /usr/bin/ld
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/

EXPOSE 5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data container is only in `db` container as you run command `docker run -d -t --volumes-from dbdata --name db hdf5`

if you want to get access to that data container in your app container you should also add command `volumes-from`

with this command `docker run -i -t -p 5000:5001 --link db:db --name app py-opencv` you only linking two containers. `app` container get a `/etc/hosts` configuration about db container but not about data volume.

so instead of `docker inspect app` run `docker inspect db` and you will find your data container information in mount parameter

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to access the `db` from my `app` and have the `db` write to `dbdata` then what I currently have will do that? If I also want to write from the `app` directly to `dbdata` then I need to link as you explain above? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: you can currently access your db from your app with your described configuration but if you want to access data-only container's files from your app you can't with link command, only with `volumes-from`
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volumes-from-container-volumes-from